# Apache2 uses Python CGI script, it is Security hole?

Tags: android, python, apache2, cgi

1.Hi I have Python CGI  script on Apache2 Server.

2.I want send data from apache2. Format is Json

3.Send data to mobile aplication.

4.Mobile aplication request data usefull HTTP Request Methods: GET.

5.The application uses HTTPURLCONECTION.

**But People ask, This is security hole.**  **Is it realy security hole ??**

**Solution could be Django on Apache 2 ?**
**or Solution could be SSL?**

Comment: maybe people were talking about https. anything sent over http is not secure in the sense that people could intercept the data and read them.

Comment: Thanks for advice  Shiping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hooray for worrying about security!

1. Yes. There are always security holes.
2. Use HTTPS rather than HTTP... Everywhere... (get free certificate from letsencrypt.com)
3. Submitting data should generally use POST, not GET. (POST and HTTPS means the data is encrypted during transport. GET requests data via the URL which itself isn't encrypted.
4. Mobile vs. Desktop isn't an issue
5. Json vs. whatever isn't an issue
6. Django vs. Python CGI isn't really an issue: if not properly configured either can have security issues.

Comment: Thanks for advice Peter. I beg you How secure script on server. This script  was readable writeable only eligible participants from andorid aps ? Data from Script is  private.

Comment: Can't answer that in 600-character comment. Google is your guide.